# Numpys `tensordot` and what is happening mathematically

Tags: python, computational-physics, numpy, tensor

I've encountered a program where [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) was used, so I tried looking it up but I can't really understand what this function is doing...

I feel rather confident in my understanding of tensors in a abstract context (i.e. in pure maths/physics), but I don't really understand what this `tensordot` is supposed to do. I'm also familiar with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum) (which I find much simpler to use/understand) and I think I read somewhere that one can perform the same operations with `tensordot` and `einsum`, is this true?

To maybe give a concrete example. Take a set of $B:=\{A^{[n]}\}$ of 3-tensors, i.e. $(A^{[n]})_{ijk}$ are the components (if you are familiat with physics, one might think of [MPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product_state)). A left normalized-MPS would then satisfy
$$\sum_{i_k} \left(A^{[k]i_k}\right)^\dagger A^{[k]i_k}= \operatorname{id}.$$

Apparantly one way to calculate this expression is given by the following code:

```
np.tensordot(np.conjugate(B),B,axes=([0,1],[0,1]))
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what this axes-specification here does. I tired looking it up for simpler examples (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/understanding-tensordot)) but I don't really get it.

I think it would help me immensly to see some more complex examples wirtten out in code form, i.e. with `tensordot`, but also the mathematical version in form of products of coefficients of abstract tensors.

Comment: `tensordot` uses `reshape` and `transpose` to reduce the problem to a `np.dot` call (the usual last axis, 2nd to the last axis sum of products). It may then reshape/transpose back. With newer `einsum` and `matmul` available, it is no longer that useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with `einsum`, maybe this explanation does it: `axes[0]` and `axes[1]` specify the locations of the repeated letters in the parameters of `einsum`. For instance,

```
np.tensordot(a, b, axes=[(0,2),(3,1)])
```

corresponds to

```
np.einsum('ijkl,mkni', a, b)
```

Indeed, `'ijkl'[(0,2)] == 'ik' == 'mkni'[(3,1)]`, and all the other letters are distinct.